# Books on PCB design

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

Anybody knows a good book on pcb design? I need to learn some theoretical concepts for designing  pcb for usb/ethernet application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PCB design is a wide field. Wider than you may thing at first.
I don't know if a "basic book" about PCB design exists. But books dedicated to specialized PCB design do exist.

Your example of a USB and Ethernet board is not really a generic PCB. It include "high speed digital" part. And this is not the best PCB design to start with. The risk is that it is likely to fail because of signal integrity issues. And this is not an easy thing to diagnose afterward. You may need expensive equipment, etc.

But if you design the PCB carefully, it might be OK.

I have two books to recommend about that subject:

- Electromagnetic compatibility Engineering by Henry Ott.
- High-Speed Circuit Board Signal Integrity by Stephen C. Thierauf

These books are not introductory book but are more focused on issues related to high speed digital such as USB and Ethernet designs.